# ui.bootstrap with popover on angular doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, popover, ui.bootstrap

I'm using angular 1.5.0-beta2 with bootstrap 3.3.5 and ui.bootstrap 0.14.3

I'm trying to create a popover on an li element.

in the following code i use ng-repeat on an array, and using the directive popover-template to pinpoint the location of the template file.

```
<ul id="glasses_ul" class="items_ul">
               <li ng-repeat="glass in glasses" popover-template="'views/drink-popup-template.html'" class="glass-tooltip">
               {{glass.glass_name}}
               </li> 
           </ul>
```

of course I loaded the `ui.bootstrap` module in my app.

now the weird thing is that once i use the popover-template directive, in google chrome, network tab i can see that it tries to load `template/popover/popover-template.html`

I have no idea why it tries to load that and what am I missing..

no tooltip is shown.

I also tried the directive `uib-popover-template` but I got the same results.

any ideas?

Comment: Several widgets are broken in bootstrap with angular 1.5.0-beta2. For production use I would use angular 1.4.8. UI Bootstrap will need to be updated to work with angular 1.5.x.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is hidden behind another element?

as you can see in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HyRQLmdkgmuCYE6JQ8NJ)

I added a couple of `<br/>` tags, so you can see the popover